# Positioning Validation Error Message in a SelectList

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I'm using jQuery Unobtrusive Validation in my MVC 4 project. The validiation works great but the error message for SelectLists show up underneath the list and not to the right like a textbox. Any idea why? Both generate the class`.field-validation-error`

Here is my razor html

**Selectlist: shows up underneath**

```
<div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Process)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Process, Model.ProcessList, "Select")
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Process)
</div>
```

**Textbox**

```
<div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Design_By)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Design_By,new { @class = "disableInput" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Design_By)
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code

```
<div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Process)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Process, Model.ProcessList, "Select")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Process)
    </div>

</div>
```